# git clone failure with "--stdin requires a git repository fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output"

Tags: git, clone, fatal-error

I just created a private repo on github.com with a README.md file. I tried to clone the repo on my laptop. I get the following error and teh clone fails i.e. directory/repo not created.

```
git clone https://github.com/XYZ/TestGit01.git

Cloning into 'TestGit01'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: --stdin requires a git repository
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

My OS is Windows 10

Comment: `git config --list | grep -F -- --stdin`

Comment: @phd I looked in my config file. I don't have the stdin string in it.

Comment: This is puzzling. If you can provide a [mcve], that might help others debug it.

Comment: @RT. Another guess — you have configured a template directory — either with [`git config init.templateDir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-inittemplateDir) or [`git clone --template`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---templatelttemplatedirectorygt) or you have [`git config core.hooksPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) — and there is a bug in [`post-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) hook.

Comment: @phd -- bingo! I'd configured a template directory previously to make my default branch "main" instead of "master". My c:/users/xyz/.gitconfig had the following entry: [init] templateDir = ~/.config/git/template/   I removed this entry and now am able to clone without a problem. Thank you so much. How do I make your suggestion as the answer?

Comment: @RT I made it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have configured a template directory and there is a bug in `post-checkout` hook.

Comment: @OfusJK Offtopic. Please remove it. If you have a different question ask it separately, not in comments to an unrelated question.